# Thymeleaf with springboot, error trying to check if list is empty now working

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

i'm trying to check if my list called listPersons is empty or not, but when i check i got an error like this:

> Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating
> SpringEL expression: .... Caused by:
> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception
> evaluating SpringEL expression: "#lists.isEmpty(listPersons"
> (template: "index" - line 15, col 8)

I have tried this:

```
<h2 th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(listPersons)}">No hay personas</h2>
<div th:if="${#!lists.isEmpty(listPersons)}">
```

and this:

```
 ${listPersons.isEmpty()}
```

But none of the options are working. I'm using thymeleaf-3.0.15 and springboot version 2.7.2

In my Java method i have this line:

```
model.addAttribute("listPersons", personaService.getAll());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the `conditional statements correctly`, hence you are getting the `SPEL error`

```
<div th:if="${#!lists.isEmpty(listPersons)}">
```

Use the below for your condition

```
<div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(listPersons)}">
```

Refer https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-evaluation

to get more insights.